# MongoDB: Updating the document while entirely replacing it

Tags: php, mongodb

```
db.so.insert({"name":"Bob", "sex": "Male", "location": "France"})
db.so.update({"name":"Bob"}, // search
             {"name":"Bob", "occupation":"The Builder"}) // replace
```

I need to do a full update, ie. replace the entire document with the new object, but in this case the `sex` and `location` fields remain since I'm not providing those fields in the update query.

Comment: Have you tried using the [upsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/) option of the _update_?

Comment: I'm already using upsert, I believe its for when the document doesn't exist at all, it will insert it.

Comment: May be you can try this https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-findOneAndReplace/ if your intention was to replace the document.

Comment: @Veeram Thats it, thanks! If you could post as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can try ***[findAndReplace](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-findOneAndReplace/)*** if your intention was to replace the document.

Comment: `replaceOne` (since 3.2) is much faster.